# "От каждого искорка вместе костер!"

Tags: пунктуация

Уважаемые буквоеды!

Помогите расставить знаки препинания в следующем предложении-девизе:

**От каждого искорка вместе костер!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Бессоюзное сложное предложение с противопоставлением частей:

> От каждого искорка — вместе костер!

Но возможны варианты:

> - От каждого — искорка, вместе — костер!
> - От каждого искорка, вместе — костер!

Comment: Людмила, наверное, в первом Вашем варианте не противопоставление, а условие?

Comment: Это ещё один вариант. Я имела в виду: От каждого искорка, а вместе костёр.

Comment: Виктор1799, условность здесь возможный, но наименее правдоподобный вариант трактовки. 
Здесь и противопоставления как такового нет. Если говорить в смысловых категориях, то связь причинно-следственная.
По сути - согласен с Людмилой.

Answer (score 0):

От каждого искорка - вместе костер!-бессоюзное сложное предложение,первая часть обозначает условие того, о чем говорится во втором предложении